# How to use HTML in label

Tags: html, label, vuetify.js, radio-group

I have a radio list control that displays a list. I want to format the text with Bold and additional text in New Line. How do I do that in  a Label. When I add a span, it is displaying  on the UI.

```js
<v-flex> 
<v-radio-group v-model="radioGroup">
<v-radio
v-for="(accountType, index) in accountTypes"
:key= "accountType.key"
:label="accountType.name"
:value= "accountType.key"
></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
</v-flex>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<v-flex> 
<v-radio-group v-model="accountType">
<v-radio
v-for="(acctType, index) in accountTypes"
  :key= "acctType.key"                                                                  
  :value= "acctType.key"
>
<span slot="label">{{ }}</span>
</v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
</v-flex>
```

Using Span slot solved the issue